# Can I somehow cascade.PERSIST the map key in a Map<Entity, Entity>?

Tags: jpa, dictionary, eclipselink

The situation: I have a class with a Map like this:

```
@Entity
public class Bar {


@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;


@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "fooMap",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "One_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID") , 
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Two_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID") )
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "Bar")
private Map<FooOne, FooTwo> fooMap;
}
```

with key/value-classes like this (FooTwo looks more or less the same):

```
@Entity
public class FooOne  {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@Basic
private String name;
```

If I populate the map and try to persist it, I get the following exception:

> UnitOfWork(117839394)--java.lang.IllegalStateException: During synchronization >a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade >PERSIST: jpa.test.minimalExample.FooOne@2e4389ed.

because JPA cascades only to the target of the -toMany association which is the value entity.

Does JPA in general or EclipseLink as implementation offer any form of annotation to cascade actions to the key class of this map? What are my options here ?

I know adding a reference to FooOne in the FooTwo-class works (like this):

```
@Entity
public class FooTwo  {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@OneToOne(cascade = cascadeType.ALL)
private FooOne foo1;
}
```

I would rather not add any additional fields to my classes if I can avoid it.

Comment: You already use the cascade on the field, and that is the control for cascading map key+value in the JPA API (IMHO). Why EclipseLink isn't respecting it is for them to answer

Comment: So does this work in other implementations other than EclipseLink ? Can Hibernate do this for example ? Maybe I should take this to the official EclipseLink forum

Comment: I know how it works in DataNucleus JPA, since that's what I use. And it works as I described above ... put cascade on the OneToMany annotation and that applies to the related objects in that field. Yes, do take it to the EclipseLink forum and ask them

Comment: Okay, I just posted it over there. Will take some time till the thread is approved, but if I learn anything new/useful I will add it here. Thank you for your time, at least I know now that I wasn't expecting something strange or exotic out of EclipseLink...